# NodeJS: UnhandledPromiseRejection when promise is rejected before await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, unhandled-promise-rejection

I have two promises without catch blocks in the beginning and I'm doing await on both of them later with `catch` blocks. Second promise `reject`s before first promise `resolve`s. So, while I'm still `await`ing on the first promise, second promise is `reject`ed and since I have not attached the `catch` yet, it crashes the server with `UnhandledPromiseRejection`.

Is there a way to make p2's `reject` propagate to `await p2`, like it does in case when p2 `resolve`s?

PS: I cannot attach the catch in the beginning itself.

Adding the code below for reference. In stackoverflow it works fine for some reason, but when run from local, the server crashes.

```js
async function main() {
  console.log("starting");
  let p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('p1 sleeping');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('p1 awake');
      resolve('p1 resolved');
    }, 5000);
  });

  let p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('p2 sleeping');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('p2 awake');
      reject('p2 rejected');  //IMPORTANT
    }, 1000);
  });

  //Below line takes 5 seconds to execute.
  //But p2 throws error after 1 second because no .catch() is attached to it yet.
  let out1 = await p1.catch(e => {
    console.log('p1 errored', e)
  });
  console.log('p1 output', out1);

  let out2 = await p2.catch(e => {
    console.log('p2 errored', e)
  });
  console.log('p2 output', out2);
}

main().then(() => {
  console.log('stopped')
});
```

Comment: "*I'm doing `await` on them later*" - don't do that. For precisely the reason you found out. "*I cannot attach the catch in the beginning itself.*" - yes you could, what's stopping you?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code in Stack Overflow console, it still throwns an `UnhandledPromiseRejection` because you are not handling the Promise rejection (you can se the error on your browser DevTools).

You should try using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#promise.all_fail-fast_behavior) or handle each Promise result with `then()` and `catch()`.